# I want my camera to move further from the player the faster they go. Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I'm working on a 3d side scroller BMX game. It's going pretty well so far but one of the problems I'm having now is that when going very fast it's hard for the player to see the upcoming terrain and will crash into things they would otherwise easily avoid. How can I get the camera to move further back and get a wider view for the player while moving? Here's the current camera code.

```
private Vector3 _offset;
[SerializeField] private Transform target;
[SerializeField] private float smoothTime;
private Vector3 _currentVelocity = Vector3.zero;


private void Awake()
{
    _offset = transform.position - target.position;
}

private void LateUpdate()
{
    Vector3 targetPosition = target.position + _offset;
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(current: transform.position, targetPosition, ref _currentVelocity, smoothTime);
```

I'm very new to Unity and I really have no idea where to start. I tried adding a rigidbody to the camera and maybe change it's distance with .magnitude  but I'm really very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience in racing games, what you want to change should be the [FOV](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-fieldOfView.html) rather than moving further, so you can simply try this:

```
cam.fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp(playerSpeed * factor, minFOV, maxFOV);
```

Comment: I don't suppose I could get more detail on that script? I tried changing the FOV based on the player speed but couldn't figure it out so I tried reading the cameras speed by adding a Rigidbody but that didn't work either. For reference I'm making a game like Trials
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0rDSm02XFw&t=56s

Comment: Which part couldn't you figure out? You dont need to read the camera speed, just read the player speed.